# Trigger both functions in sequence

Tags: javascript

How to trigger the two (same) functions one after the other

```
function beCheerful() {
    console.log('1. not triggering');
}

function beCheerful() {
    console.log('2. triggering');
}

beCheerful();
```

Note: I would like to execute both with one call just like in Dispatch custom Event

Comment: You cannot name them the same.

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, the first function will be overwritten by the second one. JavaScript does not support function overloading. When the function is written a second time with the same name, the first function is overridden and the second one is considered.
So the function name should be unique. But you can use them by assigning them into a variable and then call them.

```
MethodOne=function beCheerful() {
    console.log('1. not triggering');
}

Methodatwo = function beCheerful() {
    console.log('2. triggering');
}

MethodOne();
Methodatwo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only ends up with **one** `beCheerful` function, because the second function declaration supercedes the first (without error). To have two separate functions, you need to use different names, and then call them in the order in which you want them to run:

```
function beCheerful1() {
    console.log('1. not triggering');
}

function beCheerful2() {
    console.log('2. triggering');
}

beCheerful1();
beCheerful2();
```

With two function expressions rather than declarations (or two declarations in separate scopes), you could have two functions with the same name, but at the point you want to use them you need two distinct identifiers/property names/whatever, since a single identifier or property can only refer to one thing. (That thing can be an array with multiple entries, or an object with multiple properties, but it's still one thing.)

For instance:

```js
const functions = {
    beCheerful1: function beCheerful() {
        // `beCheerful` is an in-scope identifier here within the
        // function's body, and functions (now) have a `name`
        // property, so:
        console.log("1. name = " + beCheerful.name);
    },
    beCheerful2: function beCheerful() {
        console.log("2. name = " + beCheerful.name);
    }
};

functions.beCheerful1();
functions.beCheerful2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger your two function at once by calling the second function in the first one, but they **must** have different names

```js
function beCheerful1() {
    console.log('beCheerful1 triggering');
    beCheerful2();
}

function beCheerful2() {
    console.log('beCheerful2 triggering');
}

beCheerful1();
```

Or create one function with parameter and call it with different params:

```js
function beCheerful(text) {
    console.log('beCheerful1 triggering');
    beCheerful2();
}


let text1 = 'first trigger';
let text2 = 'second trigger';

beCheerful(text1);
beCheerful(text2);
```

Or create an array with your strings:

```js
function beCheerful(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

let array = ['first trigger', 'second trigger'];

array.forEach(element => beCheerful(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give the same name to different functions, otherwise only the function that is specified last in turn will react.
And in order to run the functions one by one, you need to register them in the order in which you need.

```js
function beCheerful_one() {
    console.log('1. not triggering');
}

function beCheerful_two() {
    console.log('2. triggering');
}

beCheerful_one();
beCheerful_two();
```